# Global Variable Can't Use in Angular.foreach

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have a problem, my global variable can't use on outside when i use angular.foreach, but i think in javascript global variable can use. Anybody can give me solution ? Thanks

**UPDATE**

**This is my xhr to get response from data object in API**

```
HttpService("POST", url, param, function(response){

            $scope.parsing = angular.fromJson(response.data);

            $scope.result = {};

            angular.forEach($scope.parsing, function(item){

                $scope.result[item._id] =  item;

                $scope.getInclude = function(){
                    return 'templates/table.html';
                };
            });
        });
```

**This is my HTML to GET DATA BASED ON USER CLICK**

```
<tbody ng-repeat="data in result">
<tr>
<td width="20%">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="getData(data)"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i> Edit</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i> </td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

**This is my code from button getData() :**

```
$scope.getData = function(data) {
    var a;

    angular.forEach(data.tags, function(item){     
        a = item.label;
    });

    console.log(a);
};
```

**This is my data object**

```
{
            "_id": "58942caba6551fd2c334741c",
            "parent_id": "58942caba6551fd2c33473d1",
            "level": 1,
            "parent_source": 2,
            "title": "title test thread ke8",
            "url": "title-test-thread-ke8_yesp0y",
            "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.8",
            "editor_pick": 0,
            "up_vote": 1669,
            "down_vote": 103,
            "category_id": "58942caba6551fd2c3347372",
            "user_id": "58942caba6551fd2c334737a",
            "active": 1,
            "status": 1,
            "responded": "2017-02-03 14:09:31",
            "revision": 0,
            "extra": "",
            "answer_count": 6,
            "updated_at": "2017-02-03 14:10:26",
            "created_at": "2017-02-03 14:09:31",
            "tag_ids": [
                "58942caba6551fd2c3347385",
                "58942caba6551fd2c3347382",
                "58942caba6551fd2c334737f",
                "58942caba6551fd2c334737e",
                "58942caba6551fd2c3347386",
                "58942caba6551fd2c334737b",
                "58942caba6551fd2c3347380"
            ],
            "tags": [
                {
                    "_id": "58942caba6551fd2c3347386",
                    "label": "Tag Name12",
                    "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisci12",
                    "url": "tag-name12",
                    "image": "http://placehold.it/300x30012",
                    "thread_count": 0,
                    "priority": 100,
                    "related": "[]",
                    "meta_title": "",
                    "meta_description": "",
                    "meta_keyword": "",
                    "active": 1,
                    "updated_at": "2017-02-03 14:09:31",
                    "created_at": "2017-02-03 14:09:31",
                    "thread_ids": [
                        "58942caba6551fd2c334738a",
                        "58942caba6551fd2c334738b",
                        "58942caba6551fd2c334738c",
                        "58942caba6551fd2c334738d",
                        "58942caba6551fd2c334738e",
                        "58942caba6551fd2c3347390",
                        "58942caba6551fd2c3347392",
                        "58942caba6551fd2c3347394",
                        "58942caba6551fd2c334739a",
                        "58942caba6551fd2c33473a3",
                        "58942caba6551fd2c33473a4",
                        "58942caba6551fd2c33473a6",
                        "58942caba6551fd2c334740f",
                        "58942caba6551fd2c3347411",
                        "58942caba6551fd2c3347412",
                        "58942caba6551fd2c334741b",
                        "58942caba6551fd2c334741c"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "_id": "58942caba6551fd2c334737e",
                    "label": "Tag Name4",
                    "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisci4",
                    "url": "tag-name4",
                    "image": "http://placehold.it/300x3004",
                    "thread_count": 0,
                    "priority": 100,
                    "related": "[]",
                    "meta_title": "",
                    "meta_description": "",
                    "meta_keyword": "",
                    "active": 1,
                    "updated_at": "2017-02-03 14:09:31",
                    "created_at": "2017-02-03 14:09:31",
                    "thread_ids": [
                        "58942caba6551fd2c3347388",
                        "58942caba6551fd2c3347389",
                        "58942caba6551fd2c334738b",
                        "58942caba6551fd2c334738c",
                        "58942caba6551fd2c3347391",
                        "58942caba6551fd2c3347392",
                        "58942caba6551fd2c3347393",
                        "58942caba6551fd2c3347398",
                        "58942caba6551fd2c334739a",
                        "58942caba6551fd2c3347412",
                        "58942caba6551fd2c3347414",
                        "58942caba6551fd2c334741c"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "_id": "58942caba6551fd2c3347382",
                    "label": "Tag Name8",
                    "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisci8",
                    "url": "tag-name8",
                    "image": "http://placehold.it/300x3008",
                    "thread_count": 0,
                    "priority": 100,
                    "related": "[]",
                    "meta_title": "",
                    "meta_description": "",
                    "meta_keyword": "",
                    "active": 1,
                    "updated_at": "2017-02-03 14:09:31",
                    "created_at": "2017-02-03 14:09:31",
                    "thread_ids": [
                        "58942caba6551fd2c3347387",
                        "58942caba6551fd2c3347390",
                        "58942caba6551fd2c3347393",
                        "58942caba6551fd2c3347397",
                        "58942caba6551fd2c3347398",
                        "58942caba6551fd2c334739c",
                        "58942caba6551fd2c33473a0",
                        "58942caba6551fd2c33473a3",
                        "58942caba6551fd2c33473a4",
                        "58942caba6551fd2c33473a6",
                        "58942caba6551fd2c33473ab",
                        "58942caba6551fd2c33473ac",
                        "58942caba6551fd2c334740d",
                        "58942caba6551fd2c3347410",
                        "58942caba6551fd2c3347411",
                        "58942caba6551fd2c3347412",
                        "58942caba6551fd2c3347416",
                        "58942caba6551fd2c334741c",
                        "58942caba6551fd2c334741d"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "_id": "58942caba6551fd2c3347385",
                    "label": "Tag Name11",
                    "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisci11",
                    "url": "tag-name11",
                    "image": "http://placehold.it/300x30011",
                    "thread_count": 0,
                    "priority": 100,
                    "related": "[]",
                    "meta_title": "",
                    "meta_description": "",
                    "meta_keyword": "",
                    "active": 1,
                    "updated_at": "2017-02-03 14:09:31",
                    "created_at": "2017-02-03 14:09:31",
                    "thread_ids": [
                        "58942caba6551fd2c334738b",
                        "58942caba6551fd2c334738e",
                        "58942caba6551fd2c3347390",
                        "58942caba6551fd2c3347396",
                        "58942caba6551fd2c3347399",
                        "58942caba6551fd2c334739a",
                        "58942caba6551fd2c334739f",
                        "58942caba6551fd2c33473a1",
                        "58942caba6551fd2c33473ac",
                        "58942caba6551fd2c334740f",
                        "58942caba6551fd2c3347414",
                        "58942caba6551fd2c3347416",
                        "58942caba6551fd2c3347418",
                        "58942caba6551fd2c334741a",
                        "58942caba6551fd2c334741c"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "_id": "58942caba6551fd2c334737b",
                    "label": "Tag Name1",
                    "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisci1",
                    "url": "tag-name1",
                    "image": "http://placehold.it/300x3001",
                    "thread_count": 0,
                    "priority": 100,
                    "related": "[]",
                    "meta_title": "",
                    "meta_description": "",
                    "meta_keyword": "",
                    "active": 1,
                    "updated_at": "2017-02-03 14:09:31",
                    "created_at": "2017-02-03 14:09:31",
                    "thread_ids": [
                        "58942caba6551fd2c3347388",
                        "58942caba6551fd2c334738b",
                        "58942caba6551fd2c3347394",
                        "58942caba6551fd2c3347398",
                        "58942caba6551fd2c334739c",
                        "58942caba6551fd2c334739d",
                        "58942caba6551fd2c33473a4",
                        "58942caba6551fd2c33473a5",
                        "58942caba6551fd2c33473a9",
                        "58942caba6551fd2c334740d",
                        "58942caba6551fd2c334740f",
                        "58942caba6551fd2c3347412",
                        "58942caba6551fd2c3347419",
                        "58942caba6551fd2c334741a",
                        "58942caba6551fd2c334741b",
                        "58942caba6551fd2c334741c"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "_id": "58942caba6551fd2c3347380",
                    "label": "Tag Name6",
                    "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisci6",
                    "url": "tag-name6",
                    "image": "http://placehold.it/300x3006",
                    "thread_count": 0,
                    "priority": 100,
                    "related": "[]",
                    "meta_title": "",
                    "meta_description": "",
                    "meta_keyword": "",
                    "active": 1,
                    "updated_at": "2017-02-03 14:09:31",
                    "created_at": "2017-02-03 14:09:31",
                    "thread_ids": [
                        "58942caba6551fd2c334738c",
                        "58942caba6551fd2c334738f",
                        "58942caba6551fd2c3347395",
                        "58942caba6551fd2c3347396",
                        "58942caba6551fd2c334739c",
                        "58942caba6551fd2c33473a4",
                        "58942caba6551fd2c33473a8",
                        "58942caba6551fd2c33473aa",
                        "58942caba6551fd2c33473ab",
                        "58942caba6551fd2c334740d",
                        "58942caba6551fd2c334740e",
                        "58942caba6551fd2c3347411",
                        "58942caba6551fd2c3347416",
                        "58942caba6551fd2c3347418",
                        "58942caba6551fd2c3347419",
                        "58942caba6551fd2c334741a",
                        "58942caba6551fd2c334741b",
                        "58942caba6551fd2c334741c"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "_id": "58942caba6551fd2c334737f",
                    "label": "Tag Name5",
                    "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisci5",
                    "url": "tag-name5",
                    "image": "http://placehold.it/300x3005",
                    "thread_count": 0,
                    "priority": 100,
                    "related": "[]",
                    "meta_title": "",
                    "meta_description": "",
                    "meta_keyword": "",
                    "active": 1,
                    "updated_at": "2017-02-03 14:09:31",
                    "created_at": "2017-02-03 14:09:31",
                    "thread_ids": [
                        "58942caba6551fd2c3347388",
                        "58942caba6551fd2c334738c",
                        "58942caba6551fd2c3347390",
                        "58942caba6551fd2c3347391",
                        "58942caba6551fd2c3347396",
                        "58942caba6551fd2c3347397",
                        "58942caba6551fd2c3347398",
                        "58942caba6551fd2c3347399",
                        "58942caba6551fd2c334739c",
                        "58942caba6551fd2c334739f",
                        "58942caba6551fd2c33473a0",
                        "58942caba6551fd2c33473a4",
                        "58942caba6551fd2c33473a9",
                        "58942caba6551fd2c33473aa",
                        "58942caba6551fd2c3347411",
                        "58942caba6551fd2c3347414",
                        "58942caba6551fd2c3347416",
                        "58942caba6551fd2c3347418",
                        "58942caba6551fd2c334741a",
                        "58942caba6551fd2c334741c",
                        "58942caba6551fd2c334741d"
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "user": {
                "_id": "58942caba6551fd2c334737a",
                "status": "15",
                "username": "usertest5",
                "name": "User Test5",
                "email": "test@test5",
                "about": "Sebuah test user ke 5",
                "image": "http://placehold.it/300x300",
                "token": "$2y$10$lN7YtRg/j9wawJUm8XukkOBvWYMmhRX4E3p64ziQWbnhpm1HJFGd2",
                "ref_id": "",
                "login_ip": "",
                "notif_check": "2017-02-03 14:09:31",
                "updated_at": "2017-02-03 14:09:31",
                "created_at": "2017-02-03 14:09:31"
            },
            "category": {
                "_id": "58942caba6551fd2c3347372",
                "label": "Sehat",
                "active": 1,
                "url": "sehat",
                "parent_id": 0,
                "level": 0,
                "dfp_interest": "[]",
                "meta_title": "",
                "meta_description": "",
                "meta_keyword": "",
                "updated_at": "2017-02-03 14:09:31",
                "created_at": "2017-02-03 14:09:31"
            }
        }
```

Comment: What global variable? How is that related to Angular? What Angular version are you using? Where do you have this code?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer the `var a`, its related to javascript as he scoped in the tags, the version is not important here, he "have" this code here. Its mug to asking that kind of question snake. Its legal question for Stackoverflow and we all started at some point.

Comment: @lin the version is important because this is angular1 code. Some angular2 users don't know angular1 hence the tags are confusing.

Comment: @echonax Take a look at the tags, no "Angular" tag over here, just "AngularJS". Its pretty clear what he is asking.

Comment: Angular2 tag was removed.

Comment: @lin because I edited it..

Comment: im using AngularJS v1.6.1. I mean to put out variable "a" inside angular.foreach. But with my way , im using "var a" . If it wrong, can you give solution for me ?

Comment: Could you please elaborate on what's not working? What is your expected output? This should work, but `a` will always have the last `data.tag`'s value, as you overwrite it in each iteration of the `forEach` loop, and only log it to the console after that.

Comment: @AlexSzabó my expected output is label's name in data.tags arrays. data.tags contain value and i should put out "a = item.label" so i can use "a" in another function

Comment: @AlexSzabó but console.log(a) is undefined

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does work fine, here is a [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tt33v1xd/2/) of what you try to achieve. Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/37tffvh0/2/) including your object.

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);
var a = [];

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope) {

    var data = [
        {
          label: 'test'
        },
        {
          label: 'test2'
        }
    ];

    angular.forEach(data, function(item){     
        a.push(item.label);
    });

    console.log(a);
});
```

Comment: where I can put data.tags ? because from data.tags , my label can output value

Comment: actually , i edited your code "label : 'test'" to "label : data.tags" but still not working

Comment: @PriskilaNovia you could make it a global var if you need it in some other function inside your application or declaring it as a function var inside your controller. Its depending on where you need it. I updated my answer.

Comment: The output in console is [Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object] even though the code a= item.label. Im confused

Comment: @PriskilaNovia please compare your data object structure with mine or update my fiddle to reproduce your problem. Please post that fiddle here in the comments.

Comment: @PriskilaNovia still working as expected: http://jsfiddle.net/37tffvh0/1/ The last label in your object will be stored in `a`, because its the last item in your object that will override `a` while looping thru your object.

Comment: just showing the last of label's name . console.log(a) can't showing label's name as expected but showing data object for tags

Comment: @PriskilaNovia `Tag Name5` is shown in the console. Thats your label name. Whats wrong with it?

Comment: yes, but my label name is 7 not 1. Supposed to showing 7 label name

Comment: I mean my label name amount is 7

Comment: @PriskilaNovia Thats an important information. Updated the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/37tffvh0/2/ and the answer.

Comment: OMG in my console.log is "Cannot read property 'push' of undefined"

Comment: Its working like expected !!! Thank you so much :) Sorry i bother you and not accurately :))